# I select the Gnome on Wayland login option, then type my password in and press Enter. A blank screen with a blinking cursor appears

Tags: gnome

I select the Gnome on Wayland login option, then type my password in and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>. A blank screen with a blinking cursor appears,  before I could do anything there was a power shortage , after couple of hours when turned on my PC this appeared on screen

Comment: It's a little difficult to see what you're asking. Are you just curious as to why you can't log in with Gnome on Wayland, or did a power surge zap your computer?

Comment: and you said "**this** appeared on screen" what is **this**?

Comment: Buy this i mean - https://mobile.twitter.com/Aashish21311/media/grid?idx=0

Comment: Update: its working now,  i used alt+f2 and login into a separate terminal session

remove gnome with
sudo apt-get autoremove gnome-core gnome-shell gnome-session

reinstall it 
sudo apt-get install gnome-core gnome-shell gnome-session 

Ps: i still love  to know what happened and how to solve it "thx from replying"